# CSS3 Mobile Multilevel Menu: can't show the second level

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu

Good evening as the title, I'm using a CSS3 vertical menu for a mobile web page, while the first level menu open correctly, I can't say the same for the second level, that always shows up on the mouseover, I've tried many things but nothing worked properly.

I'm not a CSS3 or HTML specialist, though I guess I'm surely missing something.

The HTML code is:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width : 640px) {

 /* ---------------------------------------------
     Mobile Menu 
    --------------------------------------------- */
    .m-menu {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .m-menu li { list-style: none; }

    .m-menu li a {
        display: table;
        margin-top: 1px;
        padding: 14px 10px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #78BE20;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: middle;
        color: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition-property: background;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        transition-property: background;
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }

    .m-menu > li:first-child a { margin-top: 0; }


    .m-menu li a:hover {
        background: #555555;
        -webkit-transition-property: background;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        transition-property: background;
        transition-duration: 0.2s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }

    .m-menu li ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .m-menu li li a {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0;
        padding: 0 10px;
        height: 0;
        background: #EEEEEE;
        color: #515151;
        -webkit-transition-property: all;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        transition-property: all;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }

    .m-menu > li:hover li a {
        display: table;
        margin-top: 1px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1em;
        -webkit-transition-property: all;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        transition-property: all;
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }

    .m-menu > li:hover li a:hover {
        background: #E7E7E7;
        -webkit-transition-property: background;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        transition-property: background;
        transition-duration: 0.2s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    
    /* Second level  */
   .m-menu > li > li:hover li a {
        display: table;
        margin-top: 1px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1em;
        -webkit-transition-property: all;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        transition-property: all;
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }

}
```

```html
<ul class="m-menu">
    <li> <a href="#">MENU VOICE</a>
        <ul>
   <li><a href="#">FIRST LEVEL ITEM 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FIRST LEVEL ITEM 2</a></li>
   <li>
                <a href="#">FIRST LEVEL ITEM 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">SECOND LEVEL ITEM 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Kind regards and thank in advance for every helping hand.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

It's just some minor hierarchical hiccups:

`.m-menu > li:hover li a` is targetting all anchors, of all list items (under the first). Target the first level specifically with: `.m-menu > li:hover > ul > li > a` and `.m-menu > li > li:hover li a` is forgetting the ul parent of the third level list item: `.m-menu > li > ul > li:hover li a`

edit: I also removed the media query, so the snippet would render on desktop.

```css
 /* ---------------------------------------------
     Mobile Menu 
    --------------------------------------------- */
    .m-menu {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .m-menu li { list-style: none; }

    .m-menu li a {
        display: table;
        margin-top: 1px;
        padding: 14px 10px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #78BE20;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: middle;
        color: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition-property: background;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        transition-property: background;
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }

    .m-menu > li:first-child a { margin-top: 0; }


    .m-menu li a:hover {
        background: #555555;
        -webkit-transition-property: background;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        transition-property: background;
        transition-duration: 0.2s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }

    .m-menu li ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .m-menu li li a {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0;
        padding: 0 10px;
        height: 0;
        background: #EEEEEE;
        color: #515151;
        -webkit-transition-property: all;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        transition-property: all;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }

    .m-menu > li:hover > ul > li > a {
        display: table;
        margin-top: 1px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1em;
        -webkit-transition-property: all;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        transition-property: all;
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }

    .m-menu > li:hover li a:hover {
        background: #E7E7E7;
        -webkit-transition-property: background;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        transition-property: background;
        transition-duration: 0.2s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    
    /* Second level  */
   .m-menu > li > ul > li:hover li a {
        display: table;
        margin-top: 1px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1em;
        -webkit-transition-property: all;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        transition-property: all;
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="m-menu">
    <li> <a href="#">MENU VOICE</a>
        <ul>
   <li><a href="#">FIRST LEVEL ITEM 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FIRST LEVEL ITEM 2</a></li>
   <li>
                <a href="#">FIRST LEVEL ITEM 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">SECOND LEVEL ITEM 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Matthew, helped a lot what you have explained. Kind regards!